# How large should n be to guarantee the error in approximating ln(.5) with ln(1+x) centered at a = 0 is less than .0001?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am asked to find the number of terms such that the error of approximating ln(.5) < 0.001 using Taylor's inequality. I can do these using the remainder theorem from the alternating series test, but we are required to use Taylor's inequality.

I am struggling right now to find M such that
$ |f^{n+1}(x)| \le M$.

I have found the derivative
$|f^{n+1}(x)|= \frac{n!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$. My problem is with finding M. I know that $x \in (-.5, 0)$, and the derivative (absolute value) is decreasing. If I plug -.5 into the derivative to get M, M seems to just blow up and isn't bounded.

Is there any other way to find M in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I made the calculation for $10^{-5}$. For $10^{-4}$ the result would be $p=8.9701$ then $p=9$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3+\dots+\mathcal o(x^n)$, we just need to choose $n$ so that $1/2^n\lt1/10000$.  Since $2^{17}\gt10000$, $n=17$ will work.

For a better estimate, note that we actually have the $n$-th term equal to $(-1)^{n+1}x^n/n$ , and so we can get away with $n=13$.

Answer (score 0):

Making it general, we have (for $|x|<1$)
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac {x^n} n=\sum_{n=1}^p (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac {x^n} n+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac {x^n} n$$ and you want to know $p$ such that
$$R_p=\frac {x^{p+1}}{p+1} \leq 10^{-k}$$ that is to say
$$(p+1) \geq x^{p+1} 10^k$$
In the real domain, the only analytical solution of the equation is
$$p=-\frac{W\left[-10^k \log (x)\right]}{\log (x)}-1$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) whicch is widely used (on the search bar here, just type *Lambert* and you will find $3392$ entries). For sure, after computing $p$, you will use $\lceil p\rceil$.

For $k=5$ and $x=\frac 12$, this will give $p=11.9183$, then $\lceil p\rceil=12$.

Let us check
$$R_{11}=\frac{1}{49152}\sim 2.03\times 10^{-5} > 10^{-5}$$
$$R_{12}=\frac{1}{106496}\sim 9.39\times 10^{-6} < 10^{-5}$$

If you do not have access to this function, you can use the expansion for large values of $t$ as given in the linked page
$$W(t)= L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

From a coding point of view, there is big advantage to know in advance the number of terms to be added since, in the calculation loop, you will not have any more *IF* test (this is a very expensive operation).

Suppose that, for the same $x=\frac 12$, we want $k=100$. We should find $p=322.854$  then $\lceil p\rceil=323$. Checking again
$$R_{322}=4.81\times 10^{-100} >10^{-100}$$ $$ R_{323}=9.03\times 10^{-101} <10^{-100} $$

*Welcome to the world of the magnificent Lambert function !*